# Google Sheets - Remove OLDER Duplicate Entry, ONLY if Submitted LESS than a Day Later

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically what the title says - I have a Google Sheet, powered by a Google Form. We'd like a script that does the following:
If a duplicate entry is submitted that day, remove the older entry
If a duplicate entry is submitted more than 24 hours later, leave both entries on the sheet.

Here's what I've got, it removes the newest entry, regardless of when it was submitted:

```
  function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      //If Column E in the old entry matches Column E in the new entry
      if(row[4] == newData[j][4]){
        //Pull New Timestamp and Old Timestamp
        var newTime = Date.parse(newData[j][1]);
        var oldTime = Date.parse(row[1]);
        if (newTime-oldTime<(1000*60*60*24) && newTime>oldTime) duplicate=true; // number is milliseconds in 24 hours      
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title and your description seem to contradict each other. Based on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38997609/google-sheets-remove-duplicates-only-if-they-were-submitted-on-the-same-day) I'm assuming the description is correct and you want to remove the older duplicate only if submitted less than 24 hours before the second duplicate.

First, you're setting `duplicate=true` as soon as you enter the first `if` block, which you don't want. To only remove the **older** of the two, change your second `if` condition to

```
if (newTime-oldTime<(1000*60*60*24) && newTime>oldTime) duplicate=true;
```

This should take care of removing the newest entry since you'll only mark the row a duplicate when the time is the smaller of the two you're comparing.

**EDIT**

You could take a different approach and try removing the duplicate rows instead of adding non-duplicates to a new array. What about this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange.getValues();
var nRows = data.length;
for (var i=0; i<nRows; i++){
  var time1 = Date.parse(data[i][4]);  // Time to which you will compare the others
  for (var j=0; i<nRows; j++){
    var time2 = Date.parse(data[j][4]);  // Time to compare to the first time
    if (time1>time2 && time1-time2<(1000*60*60*24)){ // time 2 is older by less than 24 hours
      data.splice(j,1); // Remove older item
      j--; // Decrement j so it does the same row since you removed one
      nRows--; // Now have one fewer rows in data
    }
  }
}
```

This way you would be modifying one array instead of creating a second one. You could finish with the clear/write using `data` instead of `newData`.

Comment: Yep, botched that title entirely!

I edited with the new script I have in its entirety - now it does nothing at all...

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a possible new approach.